# How to write an integral like this in MathJax/LaTeX?

Tags: mathjax, integral

How can I write an integral with underlined characters evenly spaced between two integral signs like this in MathJax/LaTeX?

[image: int]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MathJax the easiest way to type it is probably:

```
\mathbf{P}((X,Y) \in B) = \iint\limits_{(x,y) \in B} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx \,dy
```

[image]

[Live example on MathB.in](http://mathb.in/39176)

If you want the two integral signs as far apart as in the picture, you could use two regular `\int` signs and wrap them in `\mathop` so that you can place limits on the combined construct.

```
\mathbf{P}((X,Y) \in B) = \mathop{\int\int}\limits_{(x,y) \in B} f_{X,Y}(x,y) \,dx \,dy
```

[image]

[Live example on MathB.in](http://mathb.in/39177)

Comment: Thank you!!!  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: +1: Cool live example!

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

```
\mathbf P((X,Y) \in B) = \iint\limits_{(x,y \in B)} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy
```

gives

[image: render]

---

Full answer:

First of all, the symbol `\iint` gives what you are looking for in terms of a double-integral sign. However, when adding the limits of integration, they appear to the side, rather than directly below. Thus, we need to make use of `\limits_{...subscript...}`.

If you want the two integral signs to be spaced out a bit more, replace `\iint` with `\int \int`, which places two seperate integral signs.